# Trying to match array values to input value but returns false in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to match an array list of numbers to an `input` number value, but every time it goes the loop it doesn't seems to find a match at all. So the scenario is if `input2` is matched to any of the values of `input1` then it should show the alerts in the `if statements`.

Am I missing something pretty obvious here?

```js
var inputValues = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var input1Val = $("#input1").val(inputValues);
      
function saveBtn() {
  var input2Val = $('#input2').val();
  var isMatched = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
    if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
      var isMatched = true;
    } else {
      isMatched = false;
    }
  }

  if(isMatched) {
    alert('is matched and should save');
  } else {
    alert('Is not matched! Error!');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" /> <br /> <br />
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="" placeholder="Enter any above shown above"/>
<button type="submit" onclick="saveBtn()">Save Value</button>
```

Comment: @alexmac I checked both `typeof()` both are strings.

Comment: Care to explain for downvote!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the `isMatched` value only on match, otherwise you will reset its value to `false` even if it matched for a prior value.

You can also break the `for` loop to avoid useless iterations:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
  if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
    isMatched = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

```js
var inputValues = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var input1Val = $("#input1").val(inputValues);
      
function saveBtn() {
  var input2Val = $('#input2').val();
  var isMatched = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
    if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
      isMatched = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if(isMatched) {
    alert('is matched and should save');
  } else {
    alert('Is not matched! Error!');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" /> <br /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="" placeholder="Enter any above shown above"/>
    <button type="submit" onclick="saveBtn()">Save Value</button>
```

Comment: What -.- I added this in my code before posting and didn't work when I tested it :/ .. But that seems to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Change it to:

```
if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
  isMatched = true; // Notice that "var" should not be added here
  break; // Not necessary, but will speed up your code
} else {
  //isMatched = false; // Remove this line
}
```

Comment: And also break the loop please ?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ. added.

Comment: Good one, or remove the else part completely without break. That too works. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

It works for 5, the last value you check against. Add `break;` if a match is found. And you should remove `var` from the loop - it does nothing. As your code is looking for a single match, the `else` part can be removed too.

So:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
    if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
      isMatched = true;
      break;
    } 
  }
```

Comment: this wont fix it the var isMatched will never be true;

Comment: @YamenNassif: Yes, it will; the `var` on that line is a no-op. But JonMark should also suggest removing it. There's also no point in setting it `false` *inside* the loop. It starts out `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems here.

1) You have to break the loop once found.

2)You are creating a new variable  `isMatched` instead of updating already existing variable. Remove the var and it should works.

```js
var inputValues = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var input1Val = $("#input1").val(inputValues);
      
function saveBtn() {
  var input2Val = $('#input2').val();
  var isMatched = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
    if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
      isMatched = true;
    }
  }

  if(isMatched) {
    alert('is matched and should save');
  } else {
    alert('Is not matched! Error!');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" /> <br /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="" placeholder="Enter any above shown above"/>
    <button type="submit" onclick="saveBtn()">Save Value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the var from here

```
if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
      var isMatched = true;
    } else {
      isMatched = false;
    }
```

and make it like this

```
if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
      isMatched = true;break;
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

whats happening is that you are always decalring new isMatched variable so the original is always false.

Comment: No, `var` has function scope, not block scope.

Comment: That was my typo, I did remove var in the true statement and still returning false.

Comment: as Suresh said you should break the loop take a look at the edit

Comment: now it should work as Yamen added break . Or  check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
      var isMatched = true; //here is the problem
    } else {
      isMatched = false;
    }
```

it should be like

```
if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
      isMatched = true;
    } else {
      isMatched = false;
    }
```

Comment: Nope, this wont fixed it. See answers below, there's no block scope in jquery/js.

Answer (score 0):

1. Removed var from isMatched inside loop.
2. Added break inside loop on successful match.

```js
var inputValues = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var input1Val = $("#input1").val(inputValues);
      
function saveBtn() {
  var input2Val = $('#input2').val();
  var isMatched = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
    if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
      isMatched = true; //Not initialized here. Removed var
      break; //added this to break out of loop.
    } 
  }

  if(isMatched) {
    alert('is matched and should save');
  } else {
    alert('Is not matched! Error!');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" /> <br /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="" placeholder="Enter any above shown above"/>
    <button type="submit" onclick="saveBtn()">Save Value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare isMatched variable outside of function.

```js
var inputValues = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var input1Val = $("#input1").val(inputValues);
var isMatched = false;

function saveBtn() {
  var input2Val = $('#input2').val();
  var isMatched = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
  console.log(typeof(inputValues[i]), typeof(input2Val));
    if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
      isMatched = true;
    } 
  }
  console.log(isMatched)

  if(isMatched) {
    alert('is matched and should save');
  } else {
    alert('Is not matched! Error!');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" /> <br /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="" placeholder="Enter any above shown above"/>
    <button type="submit" onclick="saveBtn()">Save Value</button>
```

```
var inputValues = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var input1Val = $("#input1").val(inputValues);
var isMatched = false;

function saveBtn() {
  var input2Val = $('#input2').val();
  var isMatched = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
  console.log(typeof(inputValues[i]), typeof(input2Val));
    if(inputValues[i] === input2Val) {
      isMatched = true;
    } 
  }
  console.log(isMatched)

  if(isMatched) {
    alert('is matched and should save');
  } else {
    alert('Is not matched! Error!');
  }
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" /> <br /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="" placeholder="Enter any above shown above"/>
    <button type="submit" onclick="saveBtn()">Save Value</button>
```